# How to make the mouse wheel scroll behave the same on both windows and mac os?

Tags: macos-sierra, mouse-wheel

I observe that the mouse wheel scroll direction is different on mac and windows. They are opposite. Is there a way to make them behave in the same way?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please describe how you'd actually like the mouse to behave? What do you mean by "opposite"? What have you tried? Do you wish the Windows mouse to behave like the Mac mouse, or vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was going through the system preferences and stumbled upon this option called as Scroll Direction. By default it is checked i.e., the option is set to Natural. If I uncheck the option, the behavior of the mouse wheel is same as the windows.

[image]

PS: I should have explored it before I have asked the question here. I hope this answer would be helpful for others who might have the same question :) Thanks.

Comment: But if you uncheck the scroll direction checkbox, mouse does start working as it does in windows, but then the trackpad starts behaving opposite to what it does in windows, I am also in trouble because of this behaviour of trackpad and mouse wheel on MAC. I am also looking for a solution that can actually help to make both trackpad and mouse wheel behaviour same as in windows, but had no luck till now